# SAPUI5: Suggestions required to outline my webapplication which display an online Questionnaire?

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5, I need suggestions understanding outline a Web App.

I am trying to develop an Online Questionnaire which will display questions and options and user can navigate to different questions with next and previous buttons.

Here is what I was thinking while designing:

I would first use a Page Control which will have a header that displays a Title and a footer which will contain Next and Previous buttons.

The Page will have Content which will then consist of VBOX and HBOX
for holding questions and answers.

Inside this VBOX and HBOX I will bind the text coming from my Json model or from my SAP HANA database.

Is it possible to bind values to HBOX and VBOX?

Kindly suggest more like should I use a different layout for this or some other idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion is ok. You can also use for example [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Label/preview) approach.

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <l:VerticalLayout
        class="sapUiContentPadding"
        width="100%">
        <l:content>
            <Label text="Label A (required)" labelFor="input-a"/>
            <Input id="input-a" required="true"/>
            <Label text="Label B (bold)" labelFor="input-b" design="Bold" />
            <Input id="input-b"/>
            <Label text="Label C (normal)" labelFor="input-c"/>
            <Input id="input-c"/>
        </l:content>
    </l:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Hey Jaro thank you for the suggestion. Would try this one out. Just one more question should I use Text control to show the Question Text or a Label ? Which is more appropriate or used generally?

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer. I think it is up to you which one you will choose. Label is designed for shorter text, for longer text I would recommend sap.m.Text https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Text/samples or for formatted text sap.m.FormattedText https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.FormattedText/samples